# How to read registers: RAX, RBX, RCX, RDX, RSP. RBP, RSI, RDI in C or C++?

Tags: c++, c, inline-assembly

Lets say I want to read values from those registers (and pretty all thats it) on dual core x64 CPU. How can I do this? Can I simply write something like:

```
uint64_t rax = 0, rbx = 0;
__asm__ __volatile__ (
    /* read value from rbx into rbx */
    "movq %%rdx, %0;\n"
    /* read value from rax into rax*/
    "movq %%rax, %1;\n"
    /* output args */
    : "=r" (rbx), "=r" (rax)
    : /* no input */
    /* clear both rdx and rax */
    : "%rdx", "%rax"
);
```

and then just print out `rax` and `rbx`? Cheers

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I just want to read values that are currently in those registers: `RAX, RBX, RCX, RDX, RSP. RBP, RSI, RDI` and print them out, thats it.

Comment: Your variables are called rax and rbx but you read from rdx ...

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: huh, right, need to change this, thanks! But my question was more general: is it the right way to do this?

Comment: I suggest using a good debugger, place a breakpoint, then look at the registers window.

Comment: Actually this isn't really C or C++. It's inline assembler with some compiler that you did not name. On x64.

Comment: There are better sources for random numbers.  Just use your debugger to look at register values.

Answer (score 4):

The right way to do this with gcc is with register contraints:

```
uint64_t rax = 0, rbx = 0;
__asm__("" : "=a"(rax), "=b"(rbx) ::); /* make rax and rbx take on the current values in those registers */
```

Note that you don't need any actual instructions -- the constraints tell gcc that after doing nothing, the value rax will be in rax and the value of rbx will be in rbx.

You can use the constraints `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `S`, and `D` (the latter two are for %rsi and %rdi).  You can also use `Yz` for %xmm0.  Unfortunately, there don't seem to be constraints for other specific registers.

Comment: Of course, with no inputs, the `__asm__` block could be reordered somewhat freely by the compiler.

Comment: @DietrichEpp, you could add `__volatile__`, but the point is - what does reading these registers at any given point mean, given other compiler optimizations..

Comment: @ChrisDodd: Thanks for the answer! Im using gcc and in the example I posted I used `gcc's` syntax for inline assembly. You wrote: `you don't need any actual instructions` but can I use them? I mean, is my example the right way of doing this? If so, I could pull out values from other registers I need to, doing it the same way I did, right?

Comment: @ChrisDodd: another issue came out. When I tried to compile my code on x64 Windows 7 on x64 CPU with Code::Blocks (MinGW), I got this error: `Error: bad register name `%rbx'` and `Error: bad register name `%rax'`, heres the code: http://pastie.org/private/f2ai9qiizpo2s2lsnmtpg