# "Error: bad register name `%rax'" while compiling with MinGW on 64-bit Windows 7

Tags: c++, mingw, x86-64, cpu-registers

In my previous topic: [How to read registers: RAX, RBX, RCX, RDX, RSP. RBP, RSI, RDI in C or C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20575739/how-to-read-registers-rax-rbx-rcx-rdx-rsp-rbp-rsi-rdi-in-c-or-c) I asked about reading those registers. Now I wrote a code to read (just for now on) RAX and RBX.

I'm using CodeBlocks pm 64-bit Windows 7 with MinGW as a compiler and I'm working on an x86-64 CPU. When I tried to compile the below code, I got those errors:

```
Error: bad register name `%rax'
Error: bad register name `%rbx'
```

And the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdint.h>

void read(void)
{
    uint64_t rax = 0, rbx = 0;
    __asm__ __volatile__ (
        /* read value from rbx into rbx */
        "movq %%rbx, %0;\n"
        /* read value from rax into rax*/
        "movq %%rax, %1;\n"
        /* output args */
        : "=r" (rbx), "=r" (rax)
        : /* no input */
        /* clear both rdx and rax */
        : "%rbx", "%rax"
    );

    /* print out registers content */
    std::cout << "RAX = " << rax << "\n";
    std::cout << "RBX = " << rbx << "\n";

}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    read();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are compiling 32 bit code I expect

Answer (score 4):

I suspect your error comes from the "clobber" line:

```
    : "%rbx", "%rax"
```

which should read:

```
    : "rbx", "rax"
```

(Oh, and don't ask me why!)

Edit: You will also need to compile for 64-bit, using -m64 or similar - assuming of course the MingW compiler you have is 64-bit capable in the first place.

Comment: That's strange, because with that change, your code compiles on my system. You are using 64-bit mode on the build, right?

Comment: So how can I set up my Code Blocks to compile it in 64 bit mode on Windows? On my Xubuntu I have some flags for g++ but how about Windows and Code Blocks?

Comment: I haven't used Code::Blocks for a long time (for the past several years, all my development work has been for other platforms than Windows - the past couple of years largely Linux), but first I'd use `g++ -m64 mycode.cpp` on a command-line. However, somewhere in the "project configuration", where at the very least there is a "other options", where you can type in arbitrary things, adding `-m64`.

Comment: (Of course, since you are not actually clobbering [altering] the registers RAX and RBX, you don't actually need those registers in the clobber list).

Answer (score 3):

**[MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) is a 32-bit compiler**. It doesn't support the x86-64 target so you can't use 64-bit registers like RAX. At least that's what happened before at the time of this question. I'm not sure about the situation of mingw right now but for quite a long time it didn't support producing 64-bit binaries. Besides, it's broken in many ways because it uses the ancient MSVCRT runtime library which doesn't support standard C99 `printf` format specifiers or 80-bit `long double`. The developers were also reluctant to update, or respond to (pull) requests, therefore [mingw-w64](https://mingw-w64.org/doku.php) was forked which provided a much more complete solution for Windows. It solved all the `printf` issues, have more complete support for POSIX and Win32 APIs and many more things that you can read later

If the current version of mingw *does* support x86-64 then you still need to **pass the `-m64` option** to make it output a 64-bit executable, because mingw is still a 32-bit compiler as I looked over [their installer](https://osdn.net/projects/mingw/releases/p15691) and will compile into 32-bit code by default where RAX is non-existent. See also

- [MinGW-w32 vs. MinGW](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5619341/995714)
- [What is the difference between MinGW, MinGW-w64 and MinGW-builds?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25582110/995714)
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW

But the better way would be moving to better compilers such as [mingw-w64](https://mingw-w64.org/doku.php), [TDM-GCC](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/) or Clang which support both 64-bit guest and host natively

> In 2005, MinGW-w64 was created by OneVision Software under clean room design principles, since the original MinGW project was not prompt on updating its code base, including the inclusion of several key new APIs and the much needed 64-bit support. In 2008, OneVision then donated the code to Kai Tietz, one of its lead developers, under the condition that it remain open source. It was first submitted to the original MinGW project, but refused under suspicion of using non-public or proprietary information. For many reasons, the lead developer and co-founder of the MinGW-w64 project, Kai Tietz, decided not to attempt further cooperation with MinGW.
>
> MinGW-w64 provides a more complete Win32 API implementation, including:
>
> - better C99 support
> - better POSIX Threads (pthreads) support (including the possibility to enable C++11 thread-related functionality in GCC's libstdc++)
> - GCC multilib, which allows users to install 32-bit and 64-bit libraries in parallel
> - Unicode entry point (wmain/wWinMain)
> - DDK (from ReactOS)
> - DirectX (from Wine)
> - Large file support
> - Win64 support
> - Some useful tools such as gendef (an improved version of MinGW's pexports utility), and widl (an IDL compiler, a free replacement for MIDL).
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW#MinGW-w64