# Enabling `-std=c++14` flag in Code::Blocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks, c++14, generic-lambda

I have installed Code::Blocks for Windows and want to compile C++14 code like generic lambdas but the binary version of Code::Blocks that I've installed from [codeblocks.org](http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads/26) doesn't support the flag 
`-std=c++14`.

How do I update the compiler and enable `-std=c++14` flag for Code::Blocks?

Comment: I would recommend installing MinGW-w64.  It is an active fork of the original MinGW which has now fallen into disrepair. The link given in the current top answer is one guy's particular build of MinGW-w64; however if you get it from [the official site](http://mingw-w64.org) you can use the online installer and just [pick the options you want](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29947302/meaning-of-options-in-mingw-w64-installer).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

To compile your source code using C++14 in Code::Blocks, you, first of all, need to download and install a compiler that supports C++14 features.

Here’s how you can do it on Windows:

1. Download MinGW from [here](http://nuwen.net/mingw.html) (particular build) or [from official site](http://mingw-w64.org/) to [choose options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29947302/meaning-of-options-in-mingw-w64-installer)
2. Extract it to for example: C:\ (result will be C:\MinGW)
3. Open Code::Blocks
4. Go to Settings => Compiler.
5. Go to “Toolchain Executables”.
6. In the top field “Compiler’s installation directory”, change the directory to the one where you extracted the compiler. E.g C:\MinGW.
7. Change all the necessary files under “Program Files” to match the files under C:\MinGW\bin:

[image]

8. Before you hit “OK”, go to the leftmost tab “Compiler settings”.
9. Select “Compiler Flags”.
10. For simplicity, right-click in the list somewhere and select “New Flag”:

[image]

11. Type in the following and click "OK", and tick the box of the flag you just created:

[image]

12. Lastly, you need to specify the debugger path. Go to "Settings" => "Debugger", click "Default" on the left-hand side and enter the new full path of the executable:

[image]

---

Now, try to compile a program with C++14 features:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

auto main() -> int
{
    auto add_two([](auto x, auto y){ return x + y; });

    cout << add_two("I"s, "t"s) << " works!" << endl;
}
```

Comment: I have absolutely no intention of doing this on any machine I manage, and yet I'm compelled to uptick this. This answer is *Stellar* with a capital-S.

Comment: Another thing to do is to right-click in the "Settings > Compiler" page, and add `-std=c++14` to the list of flags excluded from C builds.  Otherwise, building a `.c` file will get that flag, causing a warning.  Then, you set your project to have both `-std=c++14 -std=c11`.

Comment: I followed the procedure, the testing code compiles with no problem. But the following code still causes error `char *m_data = new char[14]{ "Hello, World!" };` this line of code compiles on VS 2015 though.

Comment: Hi Andreas,  I have one program in which "codecvt"(#include <codecvt>) directory is included. After following above steps still i am getting error message like "fatal error: codecvt: No such file or directory". Please give me a solution to resolve issue. while same code is working fine on online c++14 editor or compiler (like.Ideone,codechef etc)

Answer (score -1):

May a humble newbie make one small suggestion? A small modification to test C++14 code, to allow resulting .exe file to be run independently of the IDE it was created in, slightly modified test program follows:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>

 using namespace std;

 auto main() -> int
 {
     auto add_two([](auto x, auto y){ return x + y; });

     cout << add_two("I"s, "t"s) << " works!" << endl;

     cout << "press enter to continue..." << endl;
     cin.ignore(10, '\n');
     cin.get();
 }
```

Thank you all, peace to all fellow coders, especially Igor Tandetnik.