# Windows 10 (32-bit): MinGW-w64 doesnt work

Tags: c++, windows, mingw-w64

I've tried to compile my source files using minGW-w64, because of new C++14 standard but when i try to compile i got this error even all things and setup is allright i guess:

Execution of 'g++.exe   -c C:\Users\Denis\Desktop\isocpp.cpp -o C:\Users\Denis\Desktop\isocpp.o' in 'C:\Users\Denis\Desktop' failed.

[MinGW-w64 Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jB5XG.png)

My PC version is 32bit, from the official site i was notified that MinGW-w64 works for 64-32bit.

Comment: If you have a 32-bit Windows version you can't execute 64-bit apps. It sounds like you've installed a 64-bit binary somehow.   Did you use the [official installer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/installer/mingw-w64-install.exe/download), or did you download some random repackaged build?

Comment: I installed from this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31171979/enabling-std-c14-flag-in-codeblocks , it seems that this mingw download link was x64 only, and I miss understood from the official site 64-32bit version, im trying this, thanks!

Comment: OK, if you followed the link to the nuwen.net repackaging site, that page does indeed say that it only has 64-bit native binaries

Comment: Why did you not follow the instructions, and check with the publisher? minGW-**w64** / Windows 10 **32-bit** hum maybe a problem here...!!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit despite the name, it does actually publish 64-bit and 32-bit binaries (and also targets both 64-bit and 32-bit)

Comment: @M.M: I said "maybe" - it's a big clue to the OP to check bitness _with the publisher_ :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit i just miss understood the publisher and the official installer.

Comment: @DenisBalaj: Okie doke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two distinctions to make here:

- Whether gcc.exe is a 32-bit binary or a 64-bit binary
- Whether that binary will generate programs that target 32-bit or 64-bit

mingw-w64 supports all four possible combinations here. But it sounds like you have downloaded a 64-bit binary.  32-bit Windows cannot run 64-bit binaries.

To fix this, use the [official installer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/installer/mingw-w64-install.exe/download)  (warning:Sourceforge, although it is not hosted anywhere else so far as I know), or look out when downloading prepackaged builds.