# Code Blocks incorrect c++ output

Tags: c++, gcc, mingw, codeblocks

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

Sum (int a, int b)
{
    int x = a - b;
    //cout << x << " \n";
    return x;
}

int main()
{
    int s1 = Sum(3, 6);
    cout << s1;

    return 0;
}
```

System info:
*Win 7 Sp1 x64 Ultimate/Professional or Win 8.1 x64
Code Blocks 16.01 MinGW
Debugger name and version: GNU gdb (GDB) 7.6.1
compiler: GNU GCC Compiler*

This code compiles with no problems, but this IS the problem, there should be errors.

1) Function Sum, has no return value, on http://cpp.sh/ it doesn't let me compile because of this.

2) Variable's s1 value is -3 whether I write "return x" or not.

It somehow passes the value of `x` everytime BUT if I uncomment the `cout` statement above the "`return x`" everything starts to work out as expected, what the hell :) --> `s1` will have a random value when no return statement is in place (because it was not initialized prior to being used for the function call) and -3 when the `return` is there.

I've tried this on 3 separate computers and they all exhibit the same behaviour. So I don't think the machine is the problem. 
I also tried using a different compiler but I don't know if I configured them correctly and they don't have a debugger right ? I tried *Borland c++* and *Digital Mars*. *Borland* has a new version 10.1 instead of the 5.5 that codeblocks supports and I couldn't make the new one work.
I don't even know if this is a compiler or program issue ?

I'm trying to learn C++ and this is very annoying. Our teacher is using the same software in class but on *Linux* and it works perfectly.

Off topic: Is there a way to insert code with line numbers here ? First post here so i'm still new at this :).

Thank you !

Comment: Use stricter compiler options.

Comment: Which version of GCC are you using? Because like you said that should not compile with any version of any C++ compiler.

Comment: What is THE question? Why an incorrect code behaves undefinedly?

Comment: ^^ What these guys said. Case and point: https://ideone.com/b7dFUe

Comment: Wow, thanks for the fast responses.
1) How can I find out what version of GCC I'm using ?
2) the question is:
Why incorrect code compiles and behaves like this and who is the culprit ? The software, the compiler etc. and what are my solutions ?
Thanks

Comment: `g++ --version` for the version.

Comment: And what stricter compiler options should I use, I'm a beginner and I'm overwhelmed by all the different options available in the compiler menu screen. 
Also I don't think stricter compiler options would solve the problem of values being passed around without return statement ?

Comment: When an incorrect code compiles it's obviously fault of a compiler. Default Code::Blocks compiler is really old. I would suggest you using a lastest one. You can read how to install one [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31171979/enabling-std-c14-flag-in-codeblocks).

Comment: Compiler version as taken from the info on Code Blocks website:
The codeblocks-16.01mingw-setup.exe file includes additionally the GCC/G++ compiler and GDB debugger from TDM-GCC (version 4.9.2, 32 bit, SJLJ)

Comment: To fill things in a bit: C, back in the olden days, had "implicit int": function declarations with no return type indicated that the function returned `int`. That was removed for C99, but many compilers continue to support it so the old code doesn't break.

Comment: Changed compiler to what user above suggested:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31171979/enabling-std-c14-flag-in-codeblocks

And it behaves the same :(

Comment: `2) Variable's s1 value is -3 whether I write "return x" or not.` Well, you have a `-` sign instead of `+`.

Answer (score 1):

Go to "Project" -> "Build Options" -> "Compiler Settings" tab -> "Compiler Flags"

And disable [-fpermissive](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.0.4/gcc/C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html#index-fpermissive-140)

> -fpermissive Downgrade some diagnostics about nonconformant code from errors to warnings. Thus, using -fpermissive will allow some
>   nonconforming code to compile.

Or disable it using pragma on the top of your code:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-fpermissive"
```

Also you could try to add the flag "-pedantic" in "Compiler Flags" tab

BTW:

If you try [online](https://ideone.com/lBABSK):

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic error "-fpermissive"

using namespace std;

Sum (int a, int b)
{
    int x = a - b;
    //cout << x << " \n";
    return x;
}

int main()
{
    int s1 = Sum(3, 6);
    cout << s1;

    return 0;
}
```

You got exactly same behavior you described!

Comment: I don't think -fpermissive is enabled on my machine. I can't find it in the list of options.
https://postimg.org/image/qavbl3a6n/ here is a screenshot

Comment: Maybe in "Other Compiler options"?

Comment: [EDITED] added #pragma

Answer (score 0):

As Rama said, you might have enabled -fpermissive in your codeblock.
Go to **"Project" -> "Build Options" -> "Compiler Settings" tab -> "Other options"** and delete -fpermissive.