# whats the difference between mingw and mingw64

Tags: c++, mingw, mingw-w64

What's the difference between the 32 and 64 bit versions of these programs? I've seen other posts, but my question is: can 32 version compile for both bits, but mingw compiler has to be run on a 32 machine, or can the 32 bit one only compile for 32 bit machines and 64 bit only compile for 64 machines, but both can be installed on either 64 or 32? I may include a picture for better understanding of what I mean.

Comment: I don't know about mingw, but in gcc you can specify `-m64` or `-m32` to compile a 64-bit target on a 32-bit OS, and vice versa. The 32 bit version of the compiler is meant to be installed on a 32-bit architecture.

Comment: Dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25582110/what-is-the-difference-between-mingw-mingw-w64-and-mingw-builds?

Comment: @ChrisStathis mingw-w64 requires separate binaries for 32bit and 64bit , it can't be toggled with a switch