# Variable display with MinGW instead of MinGW-W64 in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, mingw, mingw-w64

I followed Microsoft's tutorial for [using MingGW-W64 in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw). I then tried the same with MinGW (see [What is the difference between MinGW, MinGW-w64 and MinGW-builds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25582110/what-is-the-difference-between-mingw-mingw-w64-and-mingw-builds) for a comparison). I noticed a difference when [watching variables](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_set-a-watch): With MinGW-W64, actual values are displayed. With MingGW, C++ internal data structure are displayed, if anything.

Can I configure the C/C++ extension to show the variable values with MinGW the same way they are displayed with MinGW-W64?