# Viewing variable values when hover mouse over it in debug mode in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-code

I am debugging a C++ program in Visual Studio Code. When I hover my mouse over a variable, I expect to see it's value in the small popup that appears, but instead I get some strange looking information. See the image for details. How can I change this? All the video and text tutorials that I found online seem to have no such issue. [image]

Comment: `std::string` is a complex little monkey and that pop-up looks to be showing you all of that complexity. There may be a "pretty printer" out there that will tell VSC to only show the part you're interested in, the character array, but my familiarity with VSC is low. I poked at it a while back and decided it wasn't my sort of tool yet. Good job on getting the debugger working. A lot of people who don't claim to be stupid don't even get that far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So its something to do with pretty printing of gdb the debugger. With MinGW its not working for STL objects like vector, string, map etc. This issue is being faced by a lot of others, found a lot of questions from past 3 months itself. The only solution that worked for me was to uninstall the existing MinGW instlattion and instead install MinGW-W64 from [here]. [MinGW and MinGW-W64 are different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25582110/what-is-the-difference-between-mingw-mingw-w64-and-mingw-builds)[2](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/)