# Does anybody know the status of www.mingw.org?

Tags: mingw

At least from 2021-01-10T15:19:40Z, I cannot access [www.mingw.org](http://www.mingw.org).
As far as I know, that is the official mingw web page.

Does anybody know the status of [www.mingw.org](http://www.mingw.org)? Or, any other suite place to ask this question?

Comment: I think they stopped paying for the domain, and minGW is long dead due to WSL

Comment: Old domain is gone.  Project is now under: https://osdn.net/projects/mingw/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I stopped using http://mingw.org/ ages ago as it was getting behind on newer Windows API additions and newer gcc versions.

Instead I really recommend [MinGW-w64](http://mingw-w64.org/), which supports both Windows 32-bit and 64-bit.

If you want to keep your old MinGW on your system and would like to give MinGW-w64 a try without interfering with your installed version, you can download a standalone build from http://winlibs.com/ that you just need to download and extract.

If you use MSYS shell you should also switch to the newer [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/), which is a lot faster.

Comment: Do you mean that mingw is totally developing on MinGW-w64 and http://mingw.org/ is abandoned?

Comment: It started out as a fork but it it has been kept way more up to date, including support for 64-bit Windows. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25582110/what-is-the-difference-between-mingw-mingw-w64-and-mingw-builds

Answer (score 2):

I guess they've stopped paying for this domain.

The good news is that MinGW is still available on [MinGW - Minimalist GNU for Windows download | SourceForge.net](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/). Note that the maintainer announced on the homepage:

> This project is in the process of moving to osdn.net/projects/mingw, you can continue to follow us there.

So you may need to go to [MinGW - Minimalist GNU for Windows Project Top Page - OSDN](https://osdn.net/projects/mingw/).

Answer (score 1):

The official website has been changed to https://gcc.gnu.org/, so rather installing [MinGW](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/) or [MinGW-w64](http://mingw-w64.org/downloads/) from sourceforge.net it is better to get [gcc snapshots](https://ftp.mpi-inf.mpg.de/mirrors/gnu/mirror/gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/snapshots/snapshots) or clone [gnu github repository](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc).
The best will be goto http://winlibs.com/ and download the latest gcc version zip and extract to your directory. As it will be an upto date version for mordern c++ verion.

Comment: Hmm, why did you mention https://gcc.gnu.org/ ?

Comment: @liki https://gcc.gnu.org/ is the official gcc website, there is no website called  http://mingw.org/  and people can read about the latest released version and their documentation.