# Why am I getting an error in VSC for writing Hello World in c?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

My code is correct but when I write `Make hello` in the terminal, there is an error.

I expected `Hello World` to appear but there was an error instead, even when everything was correct.
This is what my code looks like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf ("hello, world");
}
```

This is what it says when I type "make hello":

```
PS C:\Harvard Tutorial> make hello
make : The term 'make' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling ofthe name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ make hello
+ ~~~~    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (make:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: Do you have `make` installed and on your PATH (or whatever Windows calls it)?

Comment: Make needs to be installed. On Windows, you can install it from [MSYS2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30069830/2752075) using `pacman -S make`. It will be installed to `C:\msys64\usr\bin\make.exe`, so that directory must be in the PATH.

Comment: Note also that `make` _compiles_ the program; it doesn't _run_ it.

Comment: I installed make right now but I don't know how to add path

Comment: (Assuming you're on Windows): you can add "C:\msys64\usr\bin" to your %PATH% variable like this: 1) Start > This PC > Properties > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables > System environment variables > Path > Edit.  See also: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw

Answer (score 1):

You need to install [MinGW-w64](https://www.mingw-w64.org/) in your Windows machine. After that add `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin` to the path. You can do that by going to the control panel then go to System then Advanced system settings and then Environment variables. In that go to system variables, then to Path, and then add `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin` to the path.

To learn more, checkout this [guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw).

Comment: MinGW-w64 should be preferred, IMO. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25582110/what-is-the-difference-between-mingw-mingw-w64-and-mingw-builds

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thanks for the information. I guess I can make an edit to my answer then.

Comment: You're still linking to the non-w64 one. :P

Comment: Oh yes. Fixed it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to open the CMD (not the powershell) and write

```
where make
```

this shoud show the position for the exe of "make"
if it is in the path inside the Windows Ambient Variables.

If show a information like "unable to find", add "make" into the Windows Ambient Variables (in the path variable) and restart your pc

Answer (score -1):

For you example you can just use gcc hello.c. To use Make you need create a makefile google cmake and that will help you generate a makefile.

Comment: `make` can do simple operations without makefiles.